# Time Series plot of timestamps in monthly buckets using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a tab separated text file data.txt that contains two columns, user id and times stamp.

```
id      ts
84853   1345285747
84854   1345285747
84855   1345285747
84856   1345285747
```

How do I create a timeseries graph of the data with number of rows on the Y axis and monthly buckets on the X axis?

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475812/calculate-daily-sums-using-python-pandas should answer your question.

Comment: As far as it stands, this is not a well formulated question: you basically ask "how to import data into pandas series from a txt file, aggregate counts by day and make a plot" = "write program for me". Each of these steps is easily searchable on SO or internet...

Comment: Ok point taken on the read file into python, plot,etc. But I wasn't asking about that. Aggregate by day/month using timestamp is the core of the question, the rest was added so the answer could be be clear by using the info for context.

Comment: NW, I reckon that link gives the answer - just replace the aggregate function with count.

Comment: I do to. Thanks! Also simply having the terminology "aggregate" helped me break the back of this thing.